# 504 gateway timeout using webshot on meteor.js server on digital ocean ubuntu 16.04

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, meteor, phantomjs

Im working on a app that creates reportr on a collection, then on the server in iron router controller, i place this code to generate my pdf using webshot, then i send the pdf by email.

works like a charm on localhost but on server keeps telling me 504 gateway timeout

this is the code on my routes.js file

```
    Meteor.methods({'sendMail': sendMail});
    Router.route('generatePDF', {
      path: '/reportes/generate-pdf/:_id', // example route with _id param
      where: 'server',
      action: function() {
        // Get invoice ID parameter
        var id = this.params._id;
        var tipo = Reportes.findOne(id).tipo;
        var fecha = Reportes.findOne(id).Fechadeservicio;
        // Setting name for our generated PDF

        var fileName = fecha+"-"+tipo+"-reporte_.pdf";

        // Load NPM packages
        var webshot  = Npm.require('webshot');
        var fs       = Npm.require('fs');
        var Future   = Npm.require('fibers/future');
        var fut      = new Future();
        // Set path to your route here - Meteor.absoluteUrl() is your root url ("http://localhost:3000/")
        var url      = Meteor.absoluteUrl('reportepdf/'+id); // Meteor.absoluteUrl('path/to/your/route');
        var options = {
          renderDelay: 3000,
          paperSize: {
            format: "Letter", 
            orientation: "portrait", 
            margin: "1cm",
            phantomPath: "/usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs"
          } //papersize
        }; //options
        // Magic happens here...
        webshot(url, fileName, options, function(err) {
          if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
          } else { 
            fs.readFile(fileName, function (error,data) {
              if (error) {
                return console.log(err);
              }
              fs.unlinkSync(fileName);
              fut.return(data);
            });
          }
        });

        let pdfData = fut.wait();
        let base64String = new Buffer(pdfData).toString('base64');
        sendMail({
          to: "nubestra@gmail.com",
          from: "israel@nubestra.com",
          subject: "prueba",
          nombrepdf: fileName,
          attachment: base64String
        });
        this.response.writeHead(302, {
          'Location': "/"
        });
        this.response.end();
        //this.response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',"Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=" + fileName});
        //this.response.end(fut.wait());
      }
    });
```

I already tried setting phantomPath manually and without it, installing phantom on the host and using the one that is installed via mup automatically, increasing render delay even for 10 seconds! what else can i do?

UPDATE 26/04/2018

Found out my app is actually creating pdfs in this directory 
/bundle/bundle/programs/server/nameofpdf.pdf

`fs.unlinkSync(fileName);` is not deleting the temporary file

also that do not explain why on local is working and on server just get stuck.